# Squid on EC2 doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, squid

I create an instance using the ubuntu AMI 12.04 server 64bit and install squid3.

The only changed to the /etc/squid3/squid.conf file was:

```
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
```

per

```
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1 MY_IP_ADDRESS
```

and I can't use the squid from MY_IP_ADDRESS. Any idea what the problem is? What other thing I must change? I can connect using telnet to the 3128 port perfectly and when I type some garbage and type ENTER squid reply some HTML and log the following:

> 1336796623.133      0 MY_IP_ADDRESS NONE/400 4016 NONE error:invalid-request - NONE/- text/html

so no firewall problem neither squid.conf syntax error.

Comment: What happens when you try and used the proxy, what messages do you get back.  Anything in the squid logs?  Anything in the server logs?  Anything in the client side logs?

Comment: @EightBitTony  Thank Nothing in the squid log, and the browser just said that it connected in the status bar but nothing more. I change the debug_options ALL,1 per debug_options ALL,3 and in cache.log appear some messages related to the request, but nothing seem to be wrong. Is a really strange error. Would be nice if someone can try to reproduce it on EC2, that will just take 5min and will safe me hours or who know if days. I had spent about two days already in this issues and nothing works.

Comment: Beside, the netstat -putan show connection active from my IP and as I already said, when I increase the debug level of the squid, he put things in cache.log that confirm me that he get the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check squid access log file and if you see a line that shows 'TCP/DENIED', you may need to make sure you really changed the right configuration file and you reloaded/restarted squid process.

Comment: Thanks. My access.log don't show anything, browser said connected but don't go far. Ubuntu default squid.conf file is prepared to allow access from localhost IPs, and I just add my IP to that list. In fact, I copied the same conf file to a virtual machine in my laptop and all work fine. cache.log don't show anything useful neither, and as I said in other comments, just show something when I change the debug level.

Comment: @frankabel: Are you sure you configured the proxy server in your browser in the correct way? You can try also to run a packet capture to see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, as I said, my cache.log put some messages after raise the debug level from 1 to 3, but nothing that I can understand. Other guys at http://askubuntu.com/questions/136015/problem-with-squid-on-ec2 test and all is fine, so as they said, seem to be a ISP problem, I will test using tunnels and write here. I think that can be important know that some ISP are blocking outside squid connections in a sophisticate way, cos as I said, port 3128 is open and my browser connected and squid sent realize of the connection. Thanks again.